# Loop chmod with Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'd like to remove the execute bit from some ubuntu motd (Message of the day) files with ansible to disable some ad-like Ubuntu news.
The module should only act if files exist and permissions are wrong.

If there are no files the tasks are running fine, but as soon as a file exists, I'm getting this:

**Error Message:**

```
failed: [ip] (item={'_ansible_parsed': True, u'stat': {u'isuid': False, u'uid': 0, u'exists': True, u'attr_flags': [... redacted the rest of the file attributes from stat ...]
```

Mayboe someone can help?

Here the files of my role:

**defaults/main.yml**

```
---
motd_path: '/etc/update-motd.d'
unwanted_motd_files:
  - 10-help-text
  - 50-motd-news
```

**tasks/main.yml**

```
---
- name: Register unwanted motd files
  stat:
    path: "{{motd_path}}/{{item}}"
  register: filecheck
  with_items: "{{ unwanted_motd_files | default([]) }}"

- name: Check if unwanted motd files are executable and remove the executable bit
  file:
    path: "{{motd_path}}/{{ item }}"
    state: touch
    mode: u-x,g-x,o-x
  with_items: "{{ filecheck.results }}"
  when: item.stat.exists == true
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, solved it :)

Here the task for everyone who intends to do the same.

Only the skip/changed console output could be replaced by a nicer message.

```
- name: Register unwanted motd files
  stat:
    path: "{{motd_path}}/{{item}}"
  register: filecheck
  with_items: "{{ unwanted_motd_files | default([]) }}"

- name: Check if unwanted motd files are executable and remove the executable bit
  file:
    path: "{{motd_path}}/{{item.item}}"
    state: touch
    mode: u-x,g-x,o-x
  with_items: "{{ filecheck.results }}"
  when: item.stat.exists == true and item.stat.executable == True
```